# Turn off soft keyboard in uwp app for windows

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have an uwp app running on a handheld device running windows 10.  The handheld device has a barcode scanner and all input for the app is made using this.  So I want to prevent the keyboard coming up when a user moves the focus to any of the textbox controls.

To a large extent, the focus is handled programmatically - and I have prevented the keyboard coming up in those instances with `PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus=True`.
But the user does need to move the focus himself sometimes and I cannot find any way of preventing the keyboard coming up when he does this.

I have found articles regarding the programmatic focus mentioned above, and hiding the keyboard when the user presses enter in a textbox - and setting the readonly value to true for the control.  But these are not applicable in this case.  I want to be able to prevent it coming up ever in this app.
Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a direct way to prevent keyboard from showing up. You can surely hide the keyboard once it shows, by subscribing to *InputPane's* events:

```cs
InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += (s, e) => (s as InputPane).TryHide();
```

But this doesn't look nice. Therefore I've tried a tricky way to achieve what you want - disable the *TextBox* for hit testing and use dummy control under it to set programmatic focus. As I've tested it should work. The sample xaml:

```xml
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Border Tapped="Border_Tapped" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Width="200" Height="100" Header="Enter:" PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="True" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </Border>
    <Button Margin="20" Content="Dummy to test focus"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And the code behind:

```cs
private void Border_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry to be so long coming back to you - was on another project.  This works fine - and don't need the button, as hitting the border does the trick.