# Set focus to textbox in UWP from ViewModel

Tags: uwp, template10

Сan anyone tell me how to set focus from `ViewModel` to `TextBox` in UWP Mobile app. My senario is

1. User scan a barcode that says: manual input
2. My ViewNodel change binding on `TextBox.Visibility` from `Collapsed` to `Visible`
3. I want to trigger `SetFocus` or `Tapped` event so the marker is inside the `TextBox` and the keyboard is shown.

Comment: Have you tried setting focus? [small sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41598899/2681948)

Comment: Don't try to do this just from the ViewModel. You need some View-centric logic and the code-behind is the right place for that. Bind some behind code to a boolean property or an event on the VM.

Comment: Henk Holtman do you have any exampel. from code  behind waths the property to set foucs?

Comment: No, but did you look at the small sample from @Romasz ?

Comment: yes you may use the Control.Focus method. so from the xaml code behind based on the situation call like this yourControlName.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

Comment: There is a behavior for this in the framework, I believe

Comment: Thanks @Kiran Paul  it solved it i used the prism.event to send message from viewmodel to the code behind to set focus.

Comment: Messaging is OK but unnecessarily complex. The code-behind can (may) access the VM directly, eg to subscribe to an event.

Answer (score 3):

Although a ViewModel is not really suited for this, the best way to set a focus from a ViewModel is by creating a dependency property for it, and then binding to it.

```cs
public static class FocusExtension
{
    public static bool GetIsFocused(Control obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFocused(Control obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(FocusExtension),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (Control)d;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue != (bool)e.OldValue)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                control.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                control.LostFocus += Control_LostFocus;
            }
            else
            {
                control.GotFocus += Control_GotFocus;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Control_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (Control)sender;
        control.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, true);
        control.GotFocus -= Control_GotFocus;
    }

    private static void Control_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (Control)sender;
        control.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, false);
        control.LostFocus -= Control_LostFocus;
    }
}
```

You can bind to it like this (two way binding is recommended, as the focus will ony be set once because the property would not be set back to false after losing focus)

```xml
<TextBox extensions:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsTextBoxFocused, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```